# Is there a package manager for APL?

Tags: package-managers, apl, dyalog

Is there any package manager for APL (something like `cargo` for Rust, `npm` for Node.js or `pip` for Python)?

I'd like to contribute a package or two, but not sure how to do it other than via a GitHub repository.

Comment: To people voting to close this question: it was not for a recommendation of a tool. It was a question if any such tools exist, as I didn't find information about Tatin, Dado or APM in [APL Wiki](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Main_Page) and other resources at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no general APL package manager.

There is also no Dyalog APL package manager that has been adopted by the community at large, or by Dyalog itself, or even by a few people or organizations for that matter. There are two attempts at a package manager for Dyalog APL. First is the successor to the [previously mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751657/) APM, now named [Tatin](https://github.com/aplteam/Tatin). This is new, and I'm not aware that it is in use by anyone.

The second is [Dado](https://github.com/the-carlisle-group/Dado). This is used by the [Carlisle Group](https://github.com/the-carlisle-group) internally to manage a stack of dependent packages, some which are also open source. Dado takes a very simple approach to package management, leveraging services like GitHub and GitLab, and git repositories, instead of running its own server. Dado has been in use for a little while at the Carlisle Group, but there are no other users at this point.

Answer (score 1):

One package manager is APM - APL Package Manager:

https://github.com/theaplroom/APM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXlgY47ZS_w